# Is this the correct way to make a panels layout

Tags: theming, panels

I have a 'working' panels layout that is getting the job done, but I'm unsure if it's the right way to do it.

Basically I copied the twocol_stacked layout from [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and fitted it to my needs. The layout I'm looking for is this:

```
------------
|          |
|----------|
|  |       |
|  |       |
|  |-------|
|  |       |
|  |       |
------------
```

What shows up when in the panels lay out looks like this:

```
------------
|          |
|----------|
|  |       |
|  |       |
|----------|
|      |
|      |
--------
```

My css isn't too strong and I don't know if there is a way to make it display correctly in the panels layout window.  When I put some long text in the left side, it does push the lower div to the right the way I want, it just feels incomplete/wrong.

The css is mostly copied out of the `twocol_stacked.css` file with a few changes:

```
.panel-2col-stacked {
  /*  overflow: hidden;  */
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-top {
  width: 99.9%;
  clear: both;
}

.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-top .inside {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-first {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
* html .panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-first {
  width: 32.9%;
}

.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-first .inside {
  margin: 0 .5em 1em 0;
}

.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-last,
.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-bottom{
  float: left;
  width: 66.9%;
}

.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-last .inside {
  margin: 0 0 1em .5em;
}

.panel-2col-stacked .panel-separator {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Without the HTML this question cannot be solved, and even then it would be an HTML and CSS question which is better asked on StackOverflow as it not specifically related to Drupal. (It would be off topic here.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Panels to create your own layout over at   `/admin/structure/panels/layouts/add-flexible`

This [Video Tutorial](https://drupalize.me/videos/custom-panels-layouts?p=1137) covers on how to create one.

Basically, you add a column, and for each column you need to add a region. You can choose to use a flexible region or a fixed region, which you can resize by draging the grey bar.